# TypeScript: Can I provide a type alias for an overloaded function signature?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create a type alias for an overloaded function signature?

For example, I have a function like:

```
function whenChanged(scope: ng.IScope, fn: ()=>void): ()=>void;
function whenChanged(fn: ()=>void, truthy:any): ()=>void;
function whenChanged(a,b): ()=>void {
    //...
}
```

I would like to create type alias to that overloaded signature to save repetition, and make use of in other places where I need to describe the type of this function.

I tried:

```
type WC1 = (scope: ng.IScope, fn: ()=>void) => ()=>void;
type WC2 = (fn: ()=>void, truthy:any) => ()=>void;
type WhenChanged = WC1 | WC2;

const whenChanged: WhenChanged = (a,b) => {
    //...
};
```

But trying to use this function, I get an error along the lines of "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature".

I cannot offhand see anything in the docs about type aliasing function overloads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you already have the function `whenChanged`:

```
function whenChanged(scope: ng.IScope, fn: ()=>void): ()=>void;
function whenChanged(fn: ()=>void, truthy:any): ()=>void;
function whenChanged(a,b): ()=>void {
    //...
}
```

The *simplest* way to get a type alias for its type is to use a `typeof` [type query](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3810-type-queries):

```
type WhenChanged = typeof whenChanged;
```

---

The next, most straightforward way to create the type alias is to use an [overloaded function signature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#62-function-overloads) (which is what you were looking for):

```
type WhenChanged = {
  (scope: ng.IScope, fn: () => void): () => void;
  (fn: () => void, truthy: any): () => void;
}
```

(which is what you will see in quickinfo if you hover over the `typeof` definition in your editor.)  Note that you don't need to use an `interface` if you don't want to.

---

The next thing you could do is similar to what you were doing, but the problem is that an overload is an *intersection*, not a *union*.  It is *both* signatures:

```
type WC1 = (scope: ng.IScope, fn: ()=>void) => ()=>void;
type WC2 = (fn: ()=>void, truthy:any) => ()=>void;
type WhenChanged = WC1 & WC2; // and, not or
```

Be careful that [intersections of function signatures are not commutative](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14190), specifically because they represent overloads.  That means that the following type is not technically the same:

```
type NotWhenChanged = WC2 & WC1; // different type
```

since the overload resolution would take place in a different order.

Note that you can't call a function of type `WC1 | WC2` since the call signatures are different the compiler can't tell if the function is `WC1` or `WC2`.

---

Okay, there you go.  Hope it helps; good luck!

Comment: This is a brilliant answer; exactly what I was after! Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

After some playing, it turns out that the answer is (at least in part) to use an interface. This seems to work:

```
interface WhenChanged {
    (scope: ng.IScope, fn: ()=>void): ()=>void
    (fn: ()=>void, truthy:any): ()=>void
}

const whenChanged: WhenChanged = (a,b) => {
    //...
};
```

Comment: I think you'll find that only works when the function matches both of the required type signatures. So the moment you change `a` to `scope: ng.IScope` it's going to refuse because `IScope` isn't compatible with `()=>void`.

Comment: You can use `type` instead of `interface`; see my answer for more info

Answer (score 0):

"Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature" means a union of types isn't callable, you have to choose one type or the other.

The problem is that in the example you gave you haven't defined types for `a` and `b`, so the compiler cannot tell which of `WC1` and `WC2` is actually being used. If you change the definition of `whenChanged`:

```
const whenChanged: WhenChanged = (a: ng.IScope, b: ()=>void) => {
  return b;
};
```

now the compiler knows it can restrict the type of `whenChanged` to `WC1` so you can safely call it.

If instead of a const you had a variable and `whenChanged` could be either of `WC1` or `WC2` in ways the compiler cannot tell then you will have to use some kind of type assertion to restrict the type to one or the other before calling it:

```
(whenChanged as WC1)(some_scope, some_fn);
```

or:

```
(whenChanged as WC2)(some_fn, some_truthy);
```

What you cannot do is work out from `whenChanged` which type it contains in order to call it with the appropriate arguments. You'll have to get that information from somewhere else.

Comment: jsdw is not actually trying to call a union of function types.  The question is about overloaded function signatures, and jsdw's attempted solution was to use a union where an intersection would have been appropriate.