# Use interfaces for functions overloads - Typescript

Tags: typescript, function, interface, overloading

I am trying to make an interface to require a bunch function to implement some overloads.
Here the simplest contrived example:

```js
type Ifunction =  {
  (v1: boolean): 0 | undefined;
  (v1: string): 1 | undefined;
}

const test: Ifunction = (b) => {
    if( typeof b === "boolean") return 0;
    if( typeof b === "string") return 1;
};
// But test doesn't type-check. I get:
/*
Type '(b: string | boolean) => 1 | 0 | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Ifunction'.
  Type '1 | 0 | undefined' is not assignable to type '0 | undefined'.
    Type '1' is not assignable to type '0'.ts(2322)
*/

// Yet these work fine.
const res1 = test(true) // correctly type-check to 0
const res2 = test("true") // correctly type-check to 1
```

How do I declare correctly the interface?

- Yes I need it to be an arrow function.
- No, having `b: any` wouldn't work, because I saw that if you do that typescript just believe your interface and stops actually type-checking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: Can I provide a type alias for an overloaded function signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693612/typescript-can-i-provide-a-type-alias-for-an-overloaded-function-signature)

Comment: FYI, you can refactor your code like this: https://tsplay.dev/NdY9Xm